# Range of the function $f(x) = [x] + (x - [x])^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

If $f(x) = [x] + (x - [x])^2$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then what is $Im(f)$?

$ \text{My attempt :}$

It's easy for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because then $f(x) = x$.

But the problem I'm having is in the case when $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

I've thought this case in two subcases.

$\text{Subcase I : }$ when $x \in \mathbb{{Q}-{Z}}$ then as rational numbers are countable, I can think of the images and the pre-images are in bijection.

$\text{Subcase II : }$ when $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then I can sense about the same bijection again
but can't prove it mathematically.

And from these I would've said that as $f$ is bijection on $\mathbb{R}$ thus $\text{Im(f)} = \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone help me building a proof of these two subcases?

$[x] = \mathbb{N} \ni k: k \leq x \wedge k + 1 > x$ - greatest integer less than or equal to x.

Comment: Your notation is not clear. From context clues, I suspect I understand your notation. But, I have seen the following: $$[x] = \max\{n \in \mathbb{Z}\mid n \le x \} \\ [x] = x - \max\{n \in \mathbb{Z}\mid n \le x \}$$ The first is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ while the latter is the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: please avoid using colours to colour the text while asking questions  ,see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/why-coloured-parts-of-questions-are-removed)

Comment: I thought that the notation of greatest integer function is globally like this that's why I didn't mention it. I'll mention it now in the post.

Comment: @Pritam, the TeX notation "\lfloor x\rfloor" (inside dollar signs) becomes $\lfloor x\rfloor$, and is rarely mistaken for anything other than the greatest integer "floor" function.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, I'm just curious, where have you seen $[x]$ used to denote the fractional part of $x$? I've only ever seen $\{x\}$ used.

Comment: @BarryCipra I believe it in a book that covered both point-set topology and analysis (potentially making the notation $\{ x \}$ confusing). I do not recall which book specifically. The book may have even mentioned different notations for fractional part and suggested that $[x]$ was the author's preferred notation to avoid confusion with set-theory.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe the books I've read there [x] is used to denote the greatest integer function and {x} (read as fraction of x) is used to denote the fractional part of x. And recently in many books [x] is being written as the floor notation which BarryCipra mentioned.

Comment: @Pritam it is only more recently that I have seen $[x]$ used to denote the greatest integer function and $\{x\}$ used to denote the fractional part of $x$. Perhaps the notation is now standardized and I am merely demonstrating my age.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, thanks. It makes sense a topology/analysis book would want to avoid the ambiguity of $\{x\}$. But $[x]$ has been a standard notation, at least in number theory, as far back as I can remember, which extends to the pre-wordprocessor days when mathematicians (or their department secretaries) used archaic devices called typewriters to prepare their manuscripts (and would literally handwrite certain symbols not included among the keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can notice, that when we set $k \leq x < k + 1$, then $[x] = k$ and $(x - [x])^2$ takes all the values in range $[0, 1)$, because $\{x\} = x - [x]$ does. $\mathrm{Im}(\{x\}) = [0, 1) \implies \mathrm{Im}((\{x\})^2) = [0, 1) $.